# How can I improve the performance of a sorted join?

Tags: performance, join, azure-sql-database, query-performance

This feels like such a common question, I'll understand if it is closed but if so please suggest a better place I could ask. I have the following two tables of interest:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sessions]
(
    [Id] [int] PRIMARY KEY,
    [DateConnected] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Origin] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [TrackerId] [int] NULL,
    [Imei] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Sim] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ProtocolVersion] [tinyint] NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PacketTransmissions]
(
    [Id] [int] PRIMARY KEY,
    [RequestId] [int] NULL,
    [SessionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateProcessed] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Direction] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Sequence] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Acknowledgement] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateRecorded] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Version] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Command] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Flags] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Checksum] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Data] [varbinary](max) NULL
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TrackerId_DateConnected] ON [dbo].[Sessions]
(
    [TrackerId] ASC,
    [DateConnected] ASC
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_SessionId_DateProcessed] ON [dbo].[PacketTransmissions]
(
    [SessionId] ASC,
    [DateProcessed] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([Direction], [Sequence], [Acknowledgement], [Command])
```

My most common query, and most expensive (quite often times out now) involves listing all packet transmissions for a particular tracker.

```
DECLARE @TrackerId INT = 10
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME2 = '2018-03-10'
DECLARE @EndDate   DATETIME2 = '2018-03-12'

SELECT [PacketTransmissions].*
FROM [Sessions]
JOIN [PacketTransmissions] ON [PacketTransmissions].[SessionId] = [Sessions].[Id]
WHERE [Sessions].[TrackerId] = @TrackerId
AND [PacketTransmissions].[DateProcessed] > @StartDate
AND [PacketTransmissions].[DateProcessed] < @EndDate
ORDER BY [PacketTransmissions].[DateProcessed] DESC
```

This was good at first, but now there is a lot of data, it has slowed right down. My attempt to get the query plan today took 2 minutes, and shows that [it will be using a table scan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyYTN4XYz), rather than the index I created. Even when I [force the index](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy4tXUXYM), it is still very slow.

In comparison, if I choose a session first, and search only for packet transmissions recorded within that session, the query uses the index and is incredibly fast.

My most successful attempt to speed up the query has been to order the results first by session id, then by date processed, to match the index order. While this is not technically always correct, it is acceptable. However, even this has started to time out, and I feel like there is something wrong with my understanding of how to make the `JOIN` faster.

What can I do to improve the performance of this query?

Querying with `DATETIME` variables instead of `DATETIME2` has simplified the query plan, however it is still very slow.

- Sessions has 265,929 rows
- PacketTransmissions has 32,916,233 rows

  That works out to be 123.7 packets per session, on average.
- Some of the sessions are for unregistered devices, so they create a session, send between one and three packets, and then the session is rejected by the server.
- I will normally be debugging a registered device, so the actual number of packets per session is considerably higher, between 300 and 5000 packets per session
- Some trackers may maintain the same session for a month at a time if they have connectivity

I have in the past had a bad experience with changing the clustered index to use a non-sequential key. It results in a lot of out-of-order writes, and page splits, and the insert performance drops significantly.

The problem with the actual execution plans is that I don't want to run the database at max DTU for up to an hour, and potentially have inserts fail in the meantime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is crazy, but I like to try a bit of blue-sky-thinking every once in a while, so I'd consider adding the `TrackerId` column to the `dbo.PacketTransmissions` table to avoid the join completely.  Obviously, this means you need to modify the row-insert procedure for the table, which may or may not be feasible.

However, this change, combined with a simple index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_PacketTransmissions ON dbo.PacketTransmissions
(
    TrackerId ASC
    , DateProcessed ASC
) 
INCLUDE (Id); --not strictly required, since the primary key 
              --is always included in every non-clustered index
              --I include them just to be explicit
```

creates a query plan using a run-of-the-mill index seek, combined with a key lookup for each row returned.  As in:

[image]

To test this, I created a minimally complete verifiable example:

```
USE tempdb;

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Sessions', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.[Sessions];
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.PacketTransmissions', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.PacketTransmissions;
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sessions]
(
      [Id] int 
        CONSTRAINT PK_Sessions
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , [DateConnected] datetime NOT NULL
    , [Origin] nvarchar(max) NULL
    , [TrackerId] int NULL
    , [Imei] nvarchar(max) NULL
    , [Sim] nvarchar(max) NULL
    , [ProtocolVersion] tinyint NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PacketTransmissions]
(
      [Id] int 
        CONSTRAINT PK_PacketTransmissions 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , [RequestId] int NULL
    , [SessionId] int NOT NULL
    , [DateProcessed] datetime NOT NULL
    , [Direction] int NOT NULL
    , [Sequence] int NOT NULL
    , [Acknowledgement] int NOT NULL
    , [DateRecorded] datetime NOT NULL
    , [Version] tinyint NOT NULL
    , [Command] tinyint NOT NULL
    , [Flags] tinyint NOT NULL
    , [Checksum] tinyint NOT NULL
    , [Data] varbinary(max) NULL
    , [TrackerId] int NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.[Sessions] (Id, DateConnected, Origin, TrackerId, Imei, Sim, ProtocolVersion)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sc1.id)
    , DATEADD(DAY, CONVERT(int, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1)), '2017-01-01 00:00:00')
    , CONVERT(nvarchar(max), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(128))
    , CONVERT(int, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1))
    , CONVERT(nvarchar(40), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(38))
    , CONVERT(nvarchar(40), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(38))
    , CONVERT(tinyint, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1))
FROM sys.syscolumns sc1
    CROSS JOIN sys.syscolumns sc2;

INSERT INTO dbo.PacketTransmissions (Id, RequestId, SessionId, DateProcessed, Direction, Sequence, Acknowledgement, DateRecorded, Version, Command, Flags, Checksum, Data, TrackerId)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s.Id)
    , CONVERT(int, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1))
    , CONVERT(int, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(3))
    , DATEADD(DAY, CONVERT(int, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1)), '2017-01-01 00:00:00')
    , CONVERT(int, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1))
    , CONVERT(int, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(2))
    , CONVERT(int, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1))
    , DATEADD(DAY, CONVERT(int, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1)), '2017-01-01 00:00:00')
    , CONVERT(int, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1))
    , CONVERT(int, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1))
    , CONVERT(int, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1))
    , CONVERT(int, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1))
    , CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(128)
    , s.TrackerId
FROM dbo.[Sessions] s
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT v.n
    FROM (VALUES (0), (1))v(n)) v;
GO
```

On my system, this creates around 700,000 session rows, and double that number of transmission rows.

The query then becomes:

```
DECLARE @TrackerId int = 100;
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2017-03-10';
DECLARE @EndDate   datetime = '2017-03-12';

SELECT [PacketTransmissions].*
FROM [PacketTransmissions] 
WHERE [PacketTransmissions].[TrackerId] = @TrackerId
    AND [PacketTransmissions].[DateProcessed] > @StartDate
    AND [PacketTransmissions].[DateProcessed] < @EndDate
ORDER BY [PacketTransmissions].[DateProcessed] DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

If, as in your example, the datetime variables are selective, ie. not too far apart, the following indexes should improve the performance.  You should check if your current indexes are needed for other selections, if not, remove them.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PT_DateProcessed]
  ON [dbo].[PacketTransmissions] ( [DateProcessed] ASC )
  INCLUDE ([SessionId])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_S_TrackerSession]
  ON [dbo].[Sessions] ( [TrackerId] ASC, [Id] ASC)
```

They will allow selecting the rows you need without table access - which in the end will still be necessary, after all, you require "*" from both tables.

Answer (score 1):

I am an Oracle developer. From the execution plan I infer that for each session record, the SQL fetches more than 130 records from PacketTransmissions on an average. Though this is a negligible count, if these records (130k in total) are scattered ([ClusteringFactor](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52asktom-1735913.html)) across all or most of the pages in the CI, the optimizer will favour FTS or CI Scan against CI Seek.

One option is to rebuild the CI on PacketTransmissions using (SessionID, DateProcessed) as the CI Key, provided they are unique. But this might require frequent rebuild.

Another option is, if it is available in Azure, use Hash Table Partitioning on (SessionID, DateProcessed). For both the options please take the other SQLs accessing PacketTransmissions table into consideration and how the performance of those SQLs might get affected.

Please note that Clustering Factor is just one of the possible reasons.

Answer (score -2):

That link does **not** indicate a table scan. That is an **index** scan. With a narrow date range the date is more selective than the join so it (properly) does the date first.

Keep the PK clustered index on the two Id

Have three separate indexs

```
[PacketTransmissions].[SessionId]   
[PacketTransmissions].[DateProcessed]  
[Sessions].[TrackerId]
```

Or

```
[PacketTransmissions].[SessionId], [PacketTransmissions].[DateProcessed]   
[PacketTransmissions].[DateProcessed], [PacketTransmissions].[SessionId]  
[Sessions].[TrackerId]
```

Just my formatting - same query

```
DECLARE @TrackerId INT = 10
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME2 = '2018-03-10'
DECLARE @EndDate   DATETIME2 = '2018-03-12'

SELECT [PacketTransmissions].*
  FROM [Sessions]
  JOIN [PacketTransmissions] 
    ON [PacketTransmissions].[SessionId] = [Sessions].[Id]
   AND [Sessions].[TrackerId] = @TrackerId
   AND [PacketTransmissions].[DateProcessed] > @StartDate
   AND [PacketTransmissions].[DateProcessed] < @EndDate
 ORDER 
    BY [PacketTransmissions].[DateProcessed] DESC
```